Fraction word problem that dividing a whole into equal parts
Alice, Grace and Pauline shared the cost of a present for their father equally. Alice used $\frac{2}{3}$ of her money, Grace used $\frac{3}{4}$ of her money, Pauline used $\frac{2}{5}$ of her money.
If they had a total of $1120, how much did each girl contribute?

Where is the "32 units" come from? (How can I think of and come up with "32 units")
Thank you.

Notice that the number $32$ is the total number of small rectangles that those "bars" in your picture are divided into.
Now I will try to explain how to come up with that sort of solution.
Notice that the numerators of fractions describing how much of their money did each girl invest are: $2$, $3$ and $2$. You are told that each one of them have invested the same amount of money. Thus you want to make the common part (the one marked with "?" in your picture) splittable into both $3$ and $2$ parts. It can be achieved if you make it contain $6$ smaller rectangles each ($6$ is the least common multiplicity of $3$ and $2$). Then you fill each bar with remaining amount of small rectangles that this common part is in fact desired fraction of money. For example you add $3$ additional rectangles to first bar and then it consist of $9$ rectangles in total and thus the common part in this case is indeed equal to $\frac{2}{3}$ of the Alice's money.
Then the reasoning is just the one that is included in your book.

We have four equations linking the three unknown sum of money owned by each: $x,y,z$ and the cost $a$ of the present.
We know that $x+y+z= 1120$ and that each of the three paid one-third of the cost, that is $\frac  a 3$.
Thus: $\frac 2 3 x=\frac a 3$ and $\frac 3 4 y=\frac a 3$ and $\frac 2 5 z=\frac a 3$, from which we can recover the equations expressing $x,y,z$ in terms of $\frac a 3$.
Thus, summing all we have:

$(\frac a 3)[\frac 3 2 +\frac 4 3 + \frac 5 2]=1120$

that is: $(\frac a 3)[\dfrac {9 + 8 + 15}{6}]=(\frac a 3)[\dfrac {32}{6}]=1120.$
From which: $\frac a 3 = 35 \times 6= 210$.

your answer is brilliant! but it's not easy for beginners to understand 2/3, 3/4, 2/5 then became 3/2, 4/3, and 5/2. hope you don't mind I choose another reply on the "32 units" for the answer.

@MarkK - thanks! but it is not brilliant... it is simply algebra.

Here is a slightly different approach:
Let the amount of money each girl has be $a$, $g$ and $p$.
We therefore have $a+g+p=1120$.
Now, each girl spent the same amount so $\frac{2}{3}a=\frac{3}{4}g=\frac{2}{5}p$.
This means $g=\frac{8}{9}a$ and $p=\frac{5}{3}a=\frac{15}{9}a$
This makes the original sum $\frac{9}{9}a+\frac{8}{9}a+\frac{15}{9}a=1120$
$\frac{32}{9}a=1120$ (which explains the 32)
This means $a=315$ and she spent $\frac{2}{3}$ of this which is $210.
So each girl spent $210.
